# getJSON values each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm struggling with some JSON. I've searched high and low, and read a lot trying to grasp this but keep falling short. Any help would be most appreciated.

I currently have this set up:

```
$.getJSON('works/api', function(r) {

    $.each(r, function(i, article) {
        console.log(article);
    });

});
```

And `works/api` has the JSON:

```
{"data":[{"title":"A Quick Perspective of the Future","description":"Installation view, Site Gallery, Sheffield"},{"title":"132Kv PL-16","description":"Single colour offset print 700 x 480mm"},{"title":"LKA V.2","description":"Installation view B&B Gallery, Sheffield"},{"title":"LKA V.2","description":"Installation view B&B Gallery, Sheffield"},{"title":"Hyperbolic Paraboloid Roof","description":"Single colour offset print 700 x 480mm"},{"title":"Road and Rail Links Between Sheffield and Manchester","description":"Gelatin silver print"}]}
```

Which is created by:

```
<?php 

$data = $pages->find('works')->children()->visible();

$json = array();

$json['data']  = array();

foreach($data as $article) {

  $json['data'][] = array(
    'title' => (string)$article->title(),
    'description' => (string)$article->description(),
  );

}

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

I am trying to retrieve the 'title' and 'description' values from the JSON, so then I can go on to append them to a div on a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is an object with an array whose key is `data`, so you need to iterate `r.data`

```
$.each(r.data, function(i, article) {
    console.log(article);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Could you briefly explain the setup for this so I understand for next time? So whatever the key is, it needs to be objectName.data, then i is meaningless and article is whatever I want to call it?

Comment: @rdck `i` is the index of the current article in the array... so if you want to do a position based calculation it can be used else most of the times it is not of much use

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$.getJSON('works/api', function(r) {
    r.data.forEach( function(d) {
       console.log(d.title);
    });
});
```

i.e. get the `data` part first, then iterate over all the objects in the `data` array and print their `title`.

Or, with `$.each`:

```
$.getJSON('works/api', function(r) {
    $.each(r.data, function(d) {
       console.log(d.title);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Which part is failing specifically? Assuming if your getJSON worked and you actually get a valid `r`, then you maybe you need to do `$.each` on `r.data` instead, because `r` would simply be an object.